# Isotope - Start with specific category rather than All elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a small issue with the isotope plugin. When my web page is loaded, Isotope will display all the elements. I'd like to have it display a single category instead. How can i achieve it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Just supply a filter in the options of your initial call to isotope that will select only the items you want:

```
$('#someid').isotope({filter: '.someclassonMyCategoryElements'});
```

*PS. It would help if you show your existing code, so we all have some context to work from :)*