# Isotope Filtering - Load specific number from each category on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a number of items in each category, but I only want to show the first 3 from each category on load then, when filtered, it should show all from that category. I have found a [number of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666776/isotope-start-with-specific-category-rather-than-all-elements) about using "filter" in the options to only load a single category, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I've mocked up [a codepen](http://codepen.io/jphogan/pen/BporzQ). Right now, there are 4 elements in each category, but I want to only show 3 from each on load.

Here are a few things I've tried. 
1. I added display:none to all items in CSS, then used lt() to select the first 3 items from each class to show them on load.

```
$('.webinar.item:lt(3), .video.item:lt(3), .printable.item:lt(3)').show();
```

This worked fine on load, but on filtering all of the items would disappear once hidden initially. Isotope doesn't add a display:block to filtered items, so the CSS was overriding and hiding those items after page load. I changed the Isotope file to add a display:block; when filters, but this really messed up the animation and caused lots of jumping when filtering categories.

2) Same as above, but I set the opacity to 0 in CSS, used the following to set the first 3 items of each category to be visible but, as expected, there were simply "empty" blocks where the addt'l items would be since they were still positioned by Isotope.

`$('.webinar.item:lt(3), .video.item:lt(3), .printable.item:lt(3)').css('opacity', '1');`

As mentioned, I would like to only show the first 3 items from each category on load. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently I just needed to type this all out to come up with the answer to my own question. :) For those who have found this thread and are looking to do something similar, here's what I did.

I used jQuery to hide all items rather than CSS so it would only happen once.

I hid all the items in my list

```
$('.isotope-list .item').hide();
```

Then, used lt() to show the first 3 from each category. This allowed me to only show 3 on load and didn't mess with the filtering in any way.

```
$('.webinar.item:lt(3), .video.item:lt(3), .printable.item:lt(3)').show();
```